# How to implement Cross Browser Opacity Gradient (Not Color Gradient)

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, opacity

How can I implement cross browser opacity gradient (not color gradient)?
See following code:

```
<div style="background-color:Red;display:block;height:500px;width:500px;filter:alpha(Opacity=100, FinishOpacity=0, Style=1, StartX=0, StartY=0, FinishX=0, FinishY=500)"></div>
```

It works fine in IE but not in other browsers like firefox,safari..etc.
What is equivalent syntax for firefox? 
Please don't suggest me to use gradient image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's `-moz-linear-gradient` for recent Firefox versions and `-webkit-gradient` for WebKit browsers. Transparency for those two should be possible by using `rgba` colors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Gradients/Gradient.html

The only real 100% cross-browser compatible solution is an image though.

Comment: This answer is not correct for the question. There does not seem to be an equivalent to ancient IE's filter:alpha start/finish for mozilla or gecko via CSS.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out how to get an image to have a horizontal linear gradient opacity, so a previous div's vertical gradient can show through. This is because in my app, the user will upload the image that requires the opacity gradient, so the solution must be pure css/js.

Comment: It will work with IE, but apprently you cannot apply a linear opacity gradient to an image background. moz and gecko actually create an image when you use the rgba linear gradient, and the gradient can apparently only go in one direction. To get the effect we are after, you would either need the ability to specify one directional gradient for opacity, and another directional gradient for color gradient.

Comment: @PlayGod Your comments are a little too opaque for me to fully understand. Maybe you'll want to add another answer or question. Duly noted comment though.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @deceze,

I am writing sample css for other people having same requirement

```
top:0px;
    opacity: 0.6;       
    width: 1944px; 
    height: 896px; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 500;
background-color:#dcdcdc;
        /* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dcdcdc), to(rgba(215,212,207,0)));
        /* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dcdcdc, rgba(215,212,207,0));
        /* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
        filter:alpha(Opacity=70, FinishOpacity=0, Style=1, StartX=1242, StartY=0, FinishX=1242, FinishY=696);
        /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70, FinishOpacity=0, Style=1, StartX=1242, StartY=0, FinishX=1242, FinishY=696)";
```